# Asp.net Core process is not shutting down after IIS restarts site

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, signalr

I have an IIS8 and I have deployed an asp.net core website (using the asp.net core module)

In order to update the site with new features every now and then, I clone the site in a different folder and change the web config so that the asp.net core module starts the application from that folder. Then I copy the new files in the web site root, and I change again the web config to point to the initial path in the root.

Changing the web config should trigger (and it does) an application restart. The old process **should** die (after a gracefull shutdown) and a new process (from the new path) should start.

The problem is that the old process doesn't die at all. A new one is spawned, but the old one is just there and I have to manually kill it from the Task Manager, otherwise I cannot overwrite the new files.

I thought, since the old process should die gracefully, there must be a long running request that keeps the old process alive. The only thing that came up to my mind is that the signalR client i use in the browser pages is keeping a connection to the server, and so it keeps the old process alive.

To test this theory, I opened the site in my browser and watched the Tasks in task manager. The application's process was there. I changed the web config file and opened another tab on the same address. A new process appeared in the Task manager. But the old one was still there even after several minutes had passed. I suspected the the first browser tab was keeping a connection to the old asp.net core process. So I closed the first tab. No more than a second after I closed it, the old process was terminated.

So is my theory correct? Does signalR client prevent the asp.net core process from shutting down gracefully after a web.config change? Shouldn't the server signalR component signal the clients to disconnect (or send a disconnected event) and then let the process die?

How do I overcome this problem? I want, upon a web.config change, the old process to terminate, not hang there forever and having to kill it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly, as I've never even considered doing what you're doing, but my feeling is that this is down to changing the web.config. You're essentially orphaning the other Kestrel process. Yes, changing the web.config will trigger a restart, but it does so on the attached process. When IIS sees this changed web.config, it sees no process from that location running (since you changed the location), and thus just simply starts this new process.

If you're already deploying to a different folder, then simply edit the site in IIS and change the document root to that new directory. This will cause IIS to stop the site that's currently running (i.e. your existing process) and then start it up again, but now at the new document root location. Then you can delete the old folder if you like.

Comment: What I do works for many other asp.net core sites I have (this solution was proposed online to overcome the lack of shadow copying in asp.net core). What I do  is I use a temporary folder with the old version of the site for the duration of copying the new site files to the actual root then I switch back.

Mind you, asp.net core knows nothing about a web.config. It is IIS that uses web.config and shuts down the application. Only, in the case of this particular site the process is not dying, and the only difference from other working sites is that I have signalR.

Comment: At the end of the day, the initial problem here is how to update the site without bringing it down during the file copying process. In classic asp.net you could overwrite the whole file hierarchy and IIS would take care of everything. Shadow Copying would copy the files to a temp asp directory and start a new process (AppDomain) from there, while the existing AppDomain would terminate after serving all pending requests. No files in the root directory were locked since the app runs from the temp asp directory. But in asp.net core the app runs from the site root and the files are locked.

Comment: The solution I proposed in my answer solves all that. No locking, zero downtime, and I know for a fact it works without fail. What you're doing may be novel, but I don't think it works consistently.

Comment: I will try that too and see what happens.